# Sequelize - NodeJS - Return o function is undefined

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to understand how I can fix my code, because my function is return undefined. I am wirting my code with Sequelize and NodeJS.

```
exports.getCreditsStudent = function(sgecode,collections,grade,year){
mssql.query('SELECT total FROM [dbo].[creditosAvulsos] WHERE codsge = $sgecode1 and nivelensino_idnivelensino = $collections1 and produto_idproduto = $grade1 and ano = $year1',
{ bind:{sgecode1: sgecode, collections1: collections, grade1: grade, year1: year}, type: mssql.QueryTypes.SELECT})
.then(total => {
    return total
  })
```

}

And I call this function on my Service.js, like this:

```
examples = db.getCreditsStudent(sgecode,collections,grade,year);
```

Where and how is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getCreditsStudent` does not actually return anything. Instead it simply defines a async process. You'll need to return the promise you've defined and then either use async/await or a promise chain to use the result.

```
exports.getCreditsStudent = function(sgecode,collections,grade,year){
  return mssql.query('SELECT total FROM [dbo].[creditosAvulsos] WHERE codsge = $sgecode1 and 
  nivelensino_idnivelensino = $collections1 and produto_idproduto = $grade1 and ano =  $year1',
  { bind:{sgecode1: sgecode, collections1: collections, grade1: grade, year1: year},
  type: mssql.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(total => {
      return total
    })
}
```

And then inside an async function you can do

```
examples = await db.getCreditsStudent(sgecode,collections,grade,year);
```

or you can use

```
db.getCreditsStudent(sgecode, collections, grade, year)
.then(value => {
   examples = value;
   // whatever you want to do with examples...
});
```